# Open and Close a Lightbox Feature Without the Use of Anchor Links?

Tags: jquery, html, css, lightbox

I am looking for a way to open and close this primarily CSS-based lightbox feature with an alternative method than using anchor links, (as demonstrated in the snippet below).

I am thinking there must be some sort of JQuery function which could replace the CSS `:target` responses. Any suggestions?

```js
$('.pic > img').click(function() {
  var srcToCopy = $(this).attr('src');
  $('body').find('.imgsrc').attr('src', srcToCopy);
  $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
});

$('#customlightbox-controls').on('click', function() {
  $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pic,
#imgsrc {
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  width: 100px
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
}

.customlightbox {
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: -5;
  opacity: 0;
}

.customlightbox-imgwrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.customlightbox img {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#customlightbox-controls {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: -50px;
  right: -3px;
  z-index: 5;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  opacity: .7;
}

#close-customlightbox {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#close-customlightbox:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 2px;
  left: 14px;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#close-customlightbox:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 14px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.customlightbox:target {
  z-index: 4;
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

.customlightbox:target img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.customlightbox:target~#customlightbox-controls {
  top: -3px;
}

.customlightbox:target~#customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:after {
  width: 30px;
}

.customlightbox:target~#customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:before {
  height: 30px;
}

.lb-animate {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 1 -->
<div class="container">
  <a href="#view">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://syedimranrocks.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/flower01low1.png">
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 2 -->
<div class="container">
  <a href="#view">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/Rose-Coral-Icon-906534.png">
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 3 -->
<div class="container">
  <a href="#view">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/136645/isolated/lists/54b1517db1906889a6971939de45d2a8-purple-sunflower-cartoon.png">
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Prompt -->
<div class="customlightbox lb-animate" id="view">
  <div class="customlightbox-imgwrap">
    <img class="imgsrc" id="customlightbox-img" src="">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="customlightbox-controls" class="lb-animate">
  <a id="close-customlightbox" class="lb-animate" href="#!"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, there are A LOT of jQuery plugin for lighboxes. For ex: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

Comment: Thanks @MoshFeu, I understand that... But I am looking for a way to make this particular lightbox function work.

Comment: Your current JS seems to already be doing what you ask for. Could you clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I agree that it is working, but I am looking for an alternative method to prompt the lightbox to open and close so that it could avoid the use of anchors being added on to the URL altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `target` with some class (`.on` in this example. And toggle the class when you want to show/hide the lightbox.

But still, I strongly recommend to use a plugin because of all the edge cases, responsive, api etc.

```js
$('.pic > img').click(function() {
  var srcToCopy = $(this).attr('src');
  $('body').find('.imgsrc').attr('src', srcToCopy);
  $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
  $('.customlightbox').addClass('on');
});

$('#customlightbox-controls').on('click', function() {
  $('.customlightbox').removeClass('on');
  $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pic,
#imgsrc {
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  width: 100px
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
}

.customlightbox {
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: -5;
  opacity: 0;
}

.customlightbox-imgwrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.customlightbox img {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#customlightbox-controls {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: -50px;
  right: -3px;
  z-index: 5;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  opacity: .7;
}

#close-customlightbox {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#close-customlightbox:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 2px;
  left: 14px;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#close-customlightbox:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 14px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.customlightbox.on {
  z-index: 4;
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

.customlightbox.on img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.customlightbox.on~#customlightbox-controls {
  top: -3px;
}

.customlightbox.on~#customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:after {
  width: 30px;
}

.customlightbox.on~#customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:before {
  height: 30px;
}

.lb-animate {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 1 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="https://syedimranrocks.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/flower01low1.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 2 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/Rose-Coral-Icon-906534.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 3 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/136645/isolated/lists/54b1517db1906889a6971939de45d2a8-purple-sunflower-cartoon.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Prompt -->
<div class="customlightbox lb-animate" id="view">
  <div class="customlightbox-imgwrap">
    <img class="imgsrc" id="customlightbox-img" src="">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="customlightbox-controls" class="lb-animate">
  <a id="close-customlightbox" class="lb-animate" href="#!"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer. Actually, someone submitted a solution to another post I made, where I essentially reiterated this same issue; however, it was very similar to yours.