# Javascript: open image on modal without href

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, popup

I should open some image on an overlay without using `<a href>` and without modify code.

I have a carousel with only image, without link. I can't add anything to it, it's just something like

```
<div>
  <div><img src=""></div>
  <div><img src=""></div>
  <div><img src=""></div>
</div>
```

I should  open the image on a overlay. Do you know any plugin (if works with jquery it should be 3.5 compatible) that could help me?

Thank you

Comment: yet, hopefully you do have the `src=""` attribute populated with the images source, right? Is there any CSS+JS you tried?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211935/open-and-close-a-lightbox-feature-without-the-use-of-anchor-links